# Shop by brand on CMS Page

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, cms

How to shown Layered navigation like shop by categories or shop by brand on left side of CMS page, in Magento 2.3.5

Comment: you use any extension?

Comment: I am using claue theme with its provided extensions. like MGS Brand etc...